# Deny login to linux machine for users not in AD "Domain Admins" group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory

So I've setup an Ubuntu server running the 8.04 release. I set it up to authenticate with our Active Directory using the likewise-open package using [these instructions](http://devarthur.blogspot.com/2008/05/integrating-ubuntu-hardy-heron-804-with.html). Part of that setup was giving Domain Admin users who login to the machine sudo access.

Now I'd like to deny login rights for all domain logins except for those users that are in the "Domain Admins" group. Local users should still be able to login. Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get to answer my own question! Jim's train of thought seemed promising but I experimented with it and it doesn't look like the likewise-open LDAP authentication uses anything from the /etc/passwd file.

The correct way I got this to work was by editing /etc/security/pam_lwidentity.conf and un-commenting and editing the following section:

```
# make successful authentication dependent on membership of one of
# the following SIDs/groups/users (comma-separated)
require_membership_of = MYDOMAIN\domain^admins
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, this is done through group policy. Samba currently doesn't have any support for managing *nix clients with group policy (Samba 4 maybe??).

You can try allowing full control of the computer object for "Domain Admins", and removing all of the permissions for "everyone", but I don't think that will prevent login. I'm just wondering if not having the "Allowed to Authenticate" permission may inadvertently block logins. I'm far from being an AD expert, so this is just a guess.

[Likewise does have a product to handle this, but I think it's only in their enterprise package](http://www.likewisesoftware.com/products/likewise_enterprise/group_policy.php).

[Edit] addendum

You can try using the netgroup syntax in /etc/password.
You can verify the full name of the group your in by running "id". If your groupname has "\" or " " you may need to escape them.

At the end of your /etc/password file add the line

```
+@AdminGroup::::::/bin/bash
+@Everyone::::::/sbin/nologin
```

This was designed for nis netgroups, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: The only policies that work with the likewise-open package on linux would be related to account/password policies. Things like the "Logon Locally" policy are in their enterprise product but I'm looking for way to do it using the free one by modifying the linux system (kind of like the sudo thing).

Comment: Maybe using the netgroups syntax for /etc/password will work, I'll add it into the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't adding that cause all the domain admins to not be allowed to login? This might have promise but it would need to work the other way around - something like no logins for anyone unless they are in the sudo/domain admin group.

Comment: you right, wasn't thinking.
Fixed it, but I've still only tried this with nis/ldap

Answer (score 0):

Closing in 3 ... 2 ... 1

I can't stand when questions like this (non-programming) get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Heres some more information that might be helpful,

[Ubuntu - Joining / Logging into Windows Domains](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000384.htm)

Pete